# Put on hold messages

Tags: support

When I see a put on hold message, it will always show put on hold by someone. 
 I would like to know who these people are.  Are they moderators?

Comment: Hi. I'm AFT, nice to meet you. No, I am not a moderator. I am just a [>3k user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Cheers!

Comment: I would like to know how these people are shown

Comment: This is [explained in the help pages](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) (which also have a decent [search functionality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help)!), as is the role of [moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). For questions about the basic mechanics of the site, maybe have a good look there before asking on meta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Not necessarily mods

The users of Physics.SE who have over 3000 reputation obtain [the privilege](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to "Vote to Close" a  Question. At 5 close votes, the post is automatically "Put on Hold". After a week, its status is changed to "Closed", unless it is reopened in the meantime. This is also mentioned in our [Help Center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Moreover, users which have a gold tag badge in either of the tags of the question can single-handedly close it as a duplicate (aka "hammer"). Moderators can single-handedly close / reopen any question.

Note that you can distinguish moderators from all other users, because they have a diamond (♦) after their username.